# How do I compute mass flow rate for a compressible fluid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas

Consider the vacuum chamber in the figure. If a hole with cross section area $A_{cs}$ is created, how can I approximate the maximum mass flow rate, $\dot{m}$, for a compressible fluid (e.g. air)?
[image: Problem description]

Comment: Google 'orifice equation '. You can consider downstream pressure to be zero with upstream being atmospheric as initial condition. But you need to integrate the resulting flow at each moment as it fills the container. The downstream increases and the delta approaches zero.

Comment: Furthermore this approach assumes adiabatic flow. A real physical system has heat transfer and to be more accurate you would need to account for temperature change as flow proceeds